# How to properly use box-shadow?

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with this. I have a header with a shadow, and a content div below it. The shadow doesn't show up unless the content div has z-index -1, but then I can't click any of the elements in the content div. What am I missing?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  background-color: green;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

.body {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>
  </div>
  <div class='body'>
    <p onClick="(function() {
      alert('Testing');})()">
      TESTING
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqzXyV)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the `z-index` of the header instead of decreasing the one of the content:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  background-color: green;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:1;
}

.body {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>
  </div>
  <div class='body'>
    <p onClick="(function() {
      alert('Testing');})()">
      TESTING
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or add `z-index:0` to the container to keep the `.body` inside its stacking context and avoid it being behind the container (the issue you were facing)<sup>**1**</sup>

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.header {
  background-color: green;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

.body {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>
  </div>
  <div class='body'>
    <p onClick="(function() {
      alert('Testing');})()">
      TESTING
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

To better see the initial issue simply add a background to the container and you will notice how the `.body` is placed behind:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background:yellow;
}

.header {
  background-color: green;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

.body {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>
  </div>
  <div class='body'>
    <p onClick="(function() {
      alert('Testing');})()">
      TESTING
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

> <sup>**1**</sup>: For those with 'z-index: auto', treat the element as
>   if it created a new stacking context, but any positioned descendants
>   and descendants which actually create a new stacking context **should be**
>   **considered part of the parent stacking context, not this new one**.<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! My problem was actually that my header had `position: static` in my code

Answer (score 0):

Remove `z-index` from both header & body and remove `position:relative` from `body` to `header`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 10px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 10px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.body {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>
  </div>
  <div class='body'>
    <p onClick="(function() {
      alert('Testing');})()">
      TESTING
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By Using z index element with greater value is always in front of an element with a lower value.

instead of giving -1 to body which is not something encouraged you should give a higher z index value to your div

```
.header
{
  ......
  ......
  z-index:1;
 }
 body
 {
  .......
  .......
      z-index:0; /* NOT IMPORTANT THOUGH IF YOU'RE NOT MESSING WITH -ve Z indexes
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

why you are not trying z-index: 1; in header

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  background-color: green;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
        
}

.body {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
```